# How to add certain number of variable names to a string

Tags: python, string

Say I have 8 variables named "Channel1, Channel2... Channel8" and want to add n number of those names to a string to be used in a text file header, how could I go about doing that?

For example, if n=3, I would like the sting to be 'Channel1, Channel2, Channel3'

Comment: it may be you can provide some code, to help to understand what you want to achieve, and what you have as an input data? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `globals()`:

```
n = 3
Channel1 = 'this'
Channel2 = 'use'
Channel3 = 'globals()'

print(' '.join(globals()['Channel' + str(i + 1)] for i in range(n)))
```

You should instead consider a list:

```
n = 3
channel = ['this', 'use', 'globals()']

print(' '.join(channels[i] for i in range(n)))
```

Comment: This worked gloriously, thanks for your help!